# Flutter Gesturedetector return value of ontapped widget

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have a list:

```
List<String> myNumbers = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Above mentioned list is being used to populate Wrap widget nested with text widgets:

```
    Widget clickArea(List<String> mynumbershere) {
        return Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              for (int i = 0; i < mynumbershere.length; i++)
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print('hello');
                      print('How do I return the textvalue of the clicked text widget?');
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      mylettershere[i],
                      style: GoogleFonts.secularOne(fontSize: 72),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ],
          ),
        );
       }
```

How do I return (retrieve value of the clicked widget) inside `onTap` of the `GestureDetector`?
I was thinking thinking the following would do the trick, but it's not working.

```
onTap: (value) {
  print(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you iterate over it using a `for loop`, each one will be executed at  it's own `i` index, so you can do this:

```
   onTap: () {
    final currentText = mynumbershere[i]; 
    print(currentText);
   },
```

now every one will print it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Although your `for loop` is correct I recommend this way:

```
children: mynumbershere
      .map((value) => Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('$value');
              },
              child: Text(
                value,
                style: GoogleFonts.secularOne(fontSize: 72),
              ),
            ),
          ))
      .toList(),
```